# Make the equation align

Tags: align

How to make my equation align?

```
\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  100 - x = y      
  \[\frac{y}{x} >= 1.3\]
  (100+x)-(100+x)*z = y
  \end{document}
```

[image: no align]

I have add `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{aligned}
  100 - x = y      
  \[\frac{y}{x} >= 1.3\]
  (100+x)-(100+x)*z = y
  \end{aligned}
  \end{document}
```

It run into issue when to compile ,how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot  that:

1. To use  `aligned`, you have to be in math mode.
2. You have to specify the alignment point with an `&`. If you don't, the alignment point is the *end* of the formula – in other words, the formulæ are right-aligned.
3. Unrelated: to obtain the symbol for *greater than or equal to*, the command is `\geq` or `\ge`.

Therefore, a correct code would be

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
..............
 \[\begin{aligned}
  100 - x &= y  \\    
  \frac{y}{x} &\ge z = y \\
(100+x)-(100+x)z &= y
  \end{aligned} \]
```

or more simply

```
\begin{align*}
  100 - x &= y  \\    
  \frac{y}{x} &\ge z = y \\
(100+x)-(100+x)z &= y
\end{align*}
```